# Insert escaped quote into Postgres JSON column

Tags: json, postgresql

The data that I need to insert into a Postgres JSON column from a text file is as before:

```
"{\"server\":\"[localhost:9001]\",\"event\":\"STARTED\",\"success\":true}"
```

Inserting directly will result in the following error:

```
ERROR: invalid input syntax for type json
DETAIL: Token "\" is invalid.
```

How can I insert this data without doing text pre-processing i.e. replacing \ escape character?

Answer (score 0):

You're using the wrong quotes.

```
'{"server":"[localhost:9001]","event":"STARTED","success":true}'
```

Comment: I know, but my data source is already like that. I can do pre-processing to clean up, but is there better way?